# Send-to-messenger plugin not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

My Send-to-messenger plugin is not appearing on my website. 
Here is my config:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId            : 'xxxxx',
  autoLogAppEvents : true,
  xfbml            : true,
  version          : 'v3.0'
});
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-send-to-messenger"
  messenger_app_id="xxxxx"
  page_id="vvvvv"
  color="blue"
  size="large">
</div>
```

The html generated by this code on this page: https://www.weekendr.eu/bonsplans seems ok, but the button would still not appear.

Some elements which may help :

- I'm on prod env
- My website has https: https://www.weekendr.eu
- My app is published and online
- I'm admin and connected to FB besides
- I allow third-party cookies

Thanks !

Comment: Did you properly white-list your domain …?

Comment: I am using same way and button is also not visible for me.
Do I need to make an app live?
Note: I am using a subdomain and I am admin

Answer (score 3):

I can see your code and found you are missing to subscribe event.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('send_to_messenger', function(e) {
      // callback for events triggered by the plugin
});
```

Please find full code below :

```
  <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });

      FB.Event.subscribe('send_to_messenger', function(e) {
      // callback for events triggered by the plugin
            console.log(e);
      });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


<div class="fb-send-to-messenger" 
  messenger_app_id="<Your App ID>" 
  page_id="<Your Page ID>" 
  data-ref="1" 
  color="blue" 
  size="large">
</div>
```

In extra, you need to follow below steps before you write above code:

1) Add your domain into the white list (Go to your facebook page -> setting)
2) Create webhook in your server and write below code (Code is in PHP. You can use any language)
For node js: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup

```
<?php


    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        //Write code to listen webhook request

    } else {
        $VERIFY_TOKEN = '1234';
        $mode = $_REQUEST['hub_mode'];
        $token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
        $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];

        if ($mode && $token) {

            // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
            if ($mode === 'subscribe' && $token === $VERIFY_TOKEN) {

                // Responds with the challenge token from the request
                console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
                echo $challenge;
                http_response_code(200); 

            } else {
                // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
                http_response_code(403); 
            }
        } else {
            http_response_code(403); 
        }
    }
?>
```

3) Goto apps settings  and verify your webhook
Setting URL :

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<Your App ID>/messenger/settings/
```

Now you should be able to view the "Send to Messenger" button

Note: If app is in development then Admin, developer & tester can only see this button.

Comment: Can confirm that the webhook needs to be already created for the "Send to Messenger" button to appear.

Comment: I want to implement this in angular 8. Do you know how to implement that? @Bhavesh Vavadiya

Comment: Yes, I can implement in Angular 8 @KinjalVithalani

Comment: Okay, thank you! Can you please share an example for that to me?  @Bhavesh Vavadiya

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist your domain (https://www.weekendr.eu) in the Messenger Profile for your page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting

I'm assuming you are replacing all the xxx and vvv with your actual app ID and Page ID, as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue is because my Ad blocker (uBlock) blocks the call to facebook. Disabling uBlock solve the issue.